# PHP function to output a form value?

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

I'm using this piece of code to add a form to a Wordpress taxonomy:

```
function albums_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
// this will add the custom meta field to the add new term page
?>
<div class="form-field">
    <label for="term_meta[custom_term_meta]"><?php _e( 'Example meta field', 'albums' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" id="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" value="">
    <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','albums' ); ?></p>
</div>
<?php
}
add_action( 'albums_add_form_fields', 'albums_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 2 );
```

The value is saving fine. However, how can I output on my template the value user filled out in the form ? What's the php function to use this value in front-end ?

Thanks.

Comment: echo function is just basic php stuff, study some php

Answer (score 1):

Just taking a guess, on the page where the form is being redirected to try:

`echo $_POST['term_meta']['custom_term_meta']`

Comment: It doesn't work. In fact, I do not want to display the value on the page where the form is redirected (it's reloading the same page with the correct value), but in my theme files.

Feida: I know how to use echo function but in this specific case I didn't succeed to display the value.

Comment: you need to be more specific where in your theme file? what part of the page?

Comment: I have a page that lists all the taxonomy "albums", via this function:

<?php 
$terms = get_terms('albums');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'albums').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>

I'd like this function displays not only names of the taxonomy ("album1", "album2") but also the value contained in the custom field of the taxonomy.

Comment: there is no such thing as a custom field of a taxonomy, a taxonomy term contains these variables: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms (scroll down)

Comment: So I cannot display custom value for taxonomy ?

Comment: what you are saying doesn't make sense...what is "custom value" are you saying you want to display different taxonomy types?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my mother language and I'm a newbie. I have one taxonomy "Albums" which store different albums. I'm trying to display the cover of every album in the list of all the albums. I want not only to display the name of every album (or slug, or id, or other native fields) but also the cover. I succeed to add a new field "Cover" inside my taxonomy via the first function I posted above, but now I need to display the value of "covers" in the list of the albums. I hope my explanation is clear :)